# OpenMDAO 1.7.3 Alpha prerequisites

Tags: openmdao

The [online installation doc](http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/getting-started/install.html#installation) says OpenMDAO 1.7.3 Alpha only requires "numpy" and "scipy", yet `pip install openmdao` gives:

> Installing collected packages: six, Pygments, imagesize, pytz, babel,
>   snowballstemmer, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, alabaster,
>   sphinxcontrib-websupport, idna, chardet, certifi, urllib3, requests,
>   docutils, typing, colorama, sphinx, numpydoc, decorator, networkx,
>   sqlitedict, pyparsing, openmdao

Why are there so many prerequisites? Am I doing something wrong?

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenMDAO does not directly depend on all of those packages, but some of the packages that we need have their own dependencies. So when you install OpenMDAO via pip, it recurses down the dependency tree and installs everything.

Answer (score 0):

That looks about right to me. Some of those things are just for building the docs, so aren't really critical for just running.